# Replace multiple lines and words using sed in a for loop

Tags: text-processing, sed, files

I have 2 files (`mac` and `uid`) with data on a Linux machine, that I want to carry to a "template", with a list, using `sed` to replace the data with variables.

**list.txt:**

```
CP00
CP01
```

**mac.txt:**

```
FF-AA-BB-AA-DD-AA
00-AA-11-AA-11-EE
```

**uid.txt:**

```
e3442342a
e43342f0a
```

**template:**

```
#Template for Cobbler:
"uid": "change1",
"mac_address": "change2",
```

I need 2 files (1st file with first "uid" and first "mac", 2nd file with second "uid" and second "mac") with the template.

I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
change1=$(cat /tmp/cobbler/uid.txt); 
change2=$(cat /tmp/cobbler/mac.txt); 
for i in `cat /tmp/cobbler/list.txt`; do 
    echo $i | cat /tmp/cobbler/template | 
      sed -e "s/change1/$change1/g" -e "s/change2/$change2/g" >> /tmp/cobbler/$i; 
done
```

The result combines the 2 names of the list `CP00CP01` and only puts the first "uid" and the first "mac".

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you expect from your example input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `cat` does not read from stdin when reading a file, so your `echo $i` is lost in the pipeline. Try running it step by step.

Comment: Is this supposed to create valid JSON output?

Comment: Yes, i am creating a valid JSON template. I need that file1 be:
CP00.txt => #Template for Cobbler:
"uid": "e3442342a", (uid1)
"mac_address": "FF-AA-BB-AA-DD-AA"... And the same with the file2, with his "uid2" and "mac2".

Comment: Don't describe the expected output in a comment, **show** the exact expected output in your question.

Comment: The output that you show is not valid JSON, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /tmp/cobbler &&
awk '
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { uids[FNR] = $1 }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { macs[FNR] = $1 }
FILENAME == ARGV[3] { outs[FNR] = $1 }
FILENAME == ARGV[4] {
    for ( outNr in outs ) {
        if ( $1 == "\"uid\":" ) {
            $2 = "\"" uids[++uidNr] "\","
        }
        if ( $1 == "\"mac_address\":" ) {
            $2 = "\"" macs[++macNr] "\","
        }
        print > (outs[outNr] ".txt")
    }
}
' uid.txt mac.txt list.txt template
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ head /tmp/cobbler/CP*
==> /tmp/cobbler/CP00.txt <==
#Template for Cobbler:
"uid": "e3442342a",
"mac_address": "FF-AA-BB-AA-DD-AA",

==> /tmp/cobbler/CP01.txt <==
#Template for Cobbler:
"uid": "e43342f0a",
"mac_address": "00-AA-11-AA-11-EE",
```

Comment: It works! Could it work, for example, for 30 Macs and 30 uids?

Comment: @henrolos sure, it could work on millions.

Comment: And, if you do have millions, use Ed's solution and not mine. Mine will also work with millions but it will be much, much, much slower.

Comment: Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working for various reasons. First, `change1=$(cat /tmp/cobbler/uid.txt);`  puts the entire contents of `/tmp/cobbler/uid.txt` into a single variable:

```
$ echo "$change1"
e3442342a
e43342f0a
```

That isn't what you want. Next, the `echo $i | cat /tmp/cobbler/template` is pointless since `cat` is being given a file so it will ignore its standard input and simply print out the contents of the file, ignoring the `$i`. In any case, `` for i in `cat file`; do... `` is bad practice, don't use it! See [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

If I have understood what you need correctly, this should give you the output you want:

```
c=1 
while read change1; do 
    listName=$(awk -v lnum="$c" 'NR==lnum' list.txt)
    change2=$(awk -v lnum="$c" 'NR==lnum' mac.txt) 
    sed "s/change1/$change1/; s/change2/$change2/" template > "$listName".txt
    (( c++ ))
done < uid.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `c=1`: this is our variable that keeps track of what line we are looking at. It is incremented by one (`(( c++ ))`) at the end of every iteration of the `while` loop.
- `while read change1; do ... ; done < uid.txt`: iterate over every line of `uid.txt`, saving each line as `$change1`.
- `listName=$(awk -v lnum="$c" 'NR==lnum' list.txt)`: use `awk` to print the `$lnum`th line of `list.txt`. We pass the value of `$c` (our counter) to `awk` as the awk variable `lnum`. Then, we tell `awk` to print the line if the current line number (`NR`) is the same as `lnum` (`NR==lnum`). Finally, we store this line as `$listName`.
- `change2=$(awk -v lnum="$c" 'NR==lnum' mac.txt)`: same as above, but this time we store `$chahge2` by getting the corresponding line from `mac.txt`.
- `sed "s/change1/$change1/; s/change2/$change2/" template > "$listName".txt`: run the `sed` command on `template`, making the replacement you asked for, and saving the output into a file named `$listName.txt`.

On your example data, this results in the following:

```
$ ls
CP00.txt  CP01.txt  list.txt  mac.txt  template  uid.txt

$ cat CP00.txt 
#Template for Cobbler:
"uid": "e3442342a",
"mac_address": "FF-AA-BB-AA-DD-AA",

$ cat CP01.txt 
#Template for Cobbler:
"uid": "e43342f0a",
"mac_address": "00-AA-11-AA-11-EE",
```